# react native (native base) - android Tabs, initialPase is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

default tab ie initial page of the tab is set correctly but it doesn't render UI, after clicking either of tab it renders respective UI of the tab selected

```js
import {Tab, Tabs,} from 'native-base';

  <Tabs 
                initialPage={0} 
                page={this.state.activeTab}
                tabContainerStyle={commonStyle.tabContainerStyle}
                onChangeTab={({ i, from }) => this.onChangeTabHandler(i, from)}
                tabBarUnderlineStyle={commonStyle.tabBarUnderlineStyle}
                locked={true} 
                >
              <Tab activeTextStyle={commonStyle.activeTextStyle} textStyle={commonStyle.textStyle} heading="ADD">
              </Tab>
              <Tab activeTextStyle={commonStyle.activeTextStyle} textStyle={commonStyle.textStyle} heading="VIEW">
              </Tab>

            </Tabs>
```

the default tab is not working

Comment: page={this.state.activeTab} what is the value of activeTab

Comment: default value is 0